# Where can I find the status of the Sitecore Cloud services?

Tags: cloud

Sitecore provides many different cloud services like Sitecore Managed Cloud, xDB Cloud, Email Cloud, Spam Check, Email Preview, Device Detection, IP Geolocation, App Center UI.

I would like to know what is the status of these services, if there is any incident or a scheduled maintenance. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Extending Sitecore Climber answer...

Sitecore Cloud Status Page is the main source, https://status.cloud.sitecore.net/.
It's frequently updated and some of the health checks are done automatically.

More on this: https://community.sitecore.net/general/f/13/t/8346.

The status page is part of cloud proactive monitoring which includes Status Page and direct e-mails to customers, read more: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/152132.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really like the RSS feed: https://status.cloud.sitecore.net/MaintenanceRSS

Answer (score 4):

as far I know this is the link where you can check status of Sitecore Cloud Services: https://status.cloud.sitecore.net/

[image]